# Activating particle system after 2 triggers on enter

Tags: unity, collision-detection, particles

I would like that

*particle system must play indefinetely at some position after **two** triggers on collision are triggered on enter.*
When game starts, particle system is deactivated.

I have make this script where I can attach particle system into prefab and I have set spawnpoint position.

1) Is it possible to activate particle system differently (without Instantiate) ?

2) How to make that ***two triggers on enter*** activate particle system? One trigger is not enough.

```
using System.Collections;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

```
using System.Collections;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class spawn_object : MonoBehaviour {

```
public Transform spawnpoint;
public GameObject prefab;

public int i=1;
// Use this for initialization

while (if <=2)
{
void OnTriggerEnter () {

    Instantiate (prefab, spawnpoint.position, spawnpoint.rotation);
            }
    i++;
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried including a variable that counts up with each trigger that enters? This seems like a fairly clear first step, so I'm wondering if you encountered any specific trouble with that we could help with

Comment: Hm, I don't know how to do that. How to differentiate two triggers?

Comment: Maybe with a comparison operator like `==` ? It sounds like you might want to work your way through some more basic tutorials and exercises to get a handle on the fundamentals of C# programming.

Comment: @DMGregory I've changed the code but I don't know how to indentify both triggers. I should have something like trigger[1] and trigger[2]. I don't know how to pass the fucntion trigger[i] argument.